# Need to convert date(12) with JOLT sepc in YYYY-MM-DD-hh:mm:ss

Tags: json, jolt

Below is the input json

```
[
  {
    "correlationId": "12345",
    "payloadFormat": "Money",
    "payload": {      
      "transactionDate": "2018010118060"      
      "name": "Dallas"      
    }
  },
  {
    "correlationId": "67895",
    "payloadFormat": "cash",
    "payload": {      
      "transactionDate": "2018010128040"      
      "name": "Texas"
      
    }
  }
]
```

Below is the expected output

```
[
  {
    "correlationId": "12345",
    "payloadFormat": "Money",
    "payload": {      
      "transactionDate": "date should be in yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"      
      "name": "Dallas"      
    }
  },
  {
    "correlationId": "67895",
    "payloadFormat": "cash",
    "payload": {      
      "transactionDate": "date should be in yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"      
      "name": "Texas"
      
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `transactionDates` string in the provided input seems to be malformed / inconsistent (different lenghts, missing seconds, see the 3rd note at the end of the answer).

With the slightly modified input:

```json
[
  {
    "correlationId": "12345",
    "payloadFormat": "Money",
    "payload": {
      "transactionDate": "201801011806012",
      "name": "Dallas"
    }
  },
  {
    "correlationId": "67895",
    "payloadFormat": "cash",
    "payload": {
      "transactionDate": "20180101084014",
      "name": "Texas"
    }
  }
]
```

and **the specification**:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "year": "=substring(@(1,payload.transactionDate),0,4)",
        "month": "=substring(@(1,payload.transactionDate),4,6)",
        "day": "=substring(@(1,payload.transactionDate),6,8)",
        "hour": "=substring(@(1,payload.transactionDate),8,10)",
        "minute": "=substring(@(1,payload.transactionDate),10,12)",
        "second": "=substring(@(1,payload.transactionDate),12,14)"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "payload": {
          "transactionDate": "=concat(@(2,year),'-',@(2,month),'-',@(2,day),' ',@(2,hour),':',@(2,minute),':',@(2,second))"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "year": "",
        "month": "",
        "day": "",
        "hour": "",
        "minute": "",
        "second": ""
      }
    }
   }
]
```

we have the output like below:

```
[ {
  "correlationId" : "12345",
  "payloadFormat" : "Money",
  "payload" : {
    "transactionDate" : "2018-01-01 18:06:01",
    "name" : "Dallas"
  }
}, {
  "correlationId" : "67895",
  "payloadFormat" : "cash",
  "payload" : {
    "transactionDate" : "2018-01-01 08:40:14",
    "name" : "Texas"
  }
} ]
```

Notes:

1. tested with https://jolt-demo.appspot.com
2. Have a look at the example showing the usage of [modify-default-beta](https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#modify-mathFunctions) operation used also in the specification above
3. if `12` in `date(12)` from the title of the post means the length of the `transactionDate` then maybe you've meant `date(14)`: (4 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2, meaning: year + month + day + hour + minutes + seconds)

Comment: Thanks a lot kasptom for this quick help